# Should Recommend Deletion in LQP queue activate the I'm Done button in First Posts and Late Answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

So, if a new user happens to something that pops up in the Low Quality Posts queue which happens to be one of their First Posts or a Late Answer to a question, it will show up in both queues and potentially be reviewable by the same person multiple times. Normally, for posts which show up in both First Posts and Late Answers, taking action in one will immediately enable the I'm Done button in the other so you don't have to take action twice.

However, in the case where a user sees it in the Low Quality Posts section first, the same actions don't apply. If I Recommend Deletion of something in the LQP queue, should I then *also* flag it as not an answer to satisfy the First Posts queue? Or should I simply be able to pass through by clicking I'm Done since I already took action on it in another queue? It seems like flagging it would just be a waste of a flag if the post is likely to be taken care of by the community in another queue.

**Note:** [This is the first post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1394201) I came across, for which I had [recommended deletion in the LQP queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1394208).

Comment: I've come across a few; what do you recommend should happen instead? If you want to delete the post it's kinda final... I sometimes check back and flag if necessary but normally the community is in agreement.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: I'm saying that seeing it in the First Posts queue, I should just be able to click I'm Done and move on since I've already "taken action" on the post.